# IDisposable: Method 'X' has multiple definitions with identical signatures

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, generics, extension-methods

### SCENARIO

---

I wrote these extension methods to initialize and/or dispose all the elements of an Array in a elegant/simplified way to avoid code repetition:

```
<HideModuleName>
Public Module ArrayExtensions

        <Extension>
        Public Sub InitializeAll(Of T As New)(ByVal sender As T())
            For index As Integer = 0 To (sender.Length - 1)
                sender(index) = New T
            Next index
        End Sub

        <Extension>
        Public Sub InitializeAll(Of T As IDisposable)(ByVal sender As T())
            ArrayExtensions.DisposeAll(sender)
            For index As Integer = 0 To (sender.Length - 1)
                sender(index) = Activator.CreateInstance(Of T)()
            Next index
        End Sub

        <Extension>
        Public Sub DisposeAll(Of T As IDisposable)(ByVal sender As T())
            For index As Integer = 0 To (sender.Length - 1)
                If (sender(index) IsNot Nothing) Then
                    sender(index).Dispose()
                    sender(index) = Nothing
                End If
            Next index
        End Sub

End Module
```

The intention is to use it in common scenarios like this:

```
Dim myCollection As MyDisposableType() = New MyDisposableType(100) {}

myCollection.InitializeAll()
myCollection.DisposeAll()
```

### PROBLEM

---

The problem I found is that the compiler is showing this error:

> 'Public Sub InitializeAll(Of T As New)(sender() As T)' has multiple
>   definitions with identical signatures.

...I don't really understand this error since `IDisposable` is a interface, I tried to remove the "**As New**" of the type parameter but still showing the same error.

### QUESTION

---

How I could adapt the type parameters of the `InitializeAll()` methods to avoid this error and still working in the expected behavior?, I mean that one method accepts an array of disposable objetcs, and the other method for non-disposable objects.

I'm aware that I could fuse/merge the logic of both methods in a single method like this below:

```
<Extension>
Public Sub InitializeAll(Of T As New)(ByVal sender As T())

    For index As Integer = 0 To (sender.Length - 1)

        If (sender(index) IsNot Nothing) Then

            If sender(index).GetType.GetInterfaces.Contains(GetType(IDisposable)) Then
                DirectCast(sender(index), IDisposable).Dispose()
                sender(index) = Nothing
            End If

        End If

        sender(index) = New T

    Next index

End Sub
```

But I prefer to have two different methods, because then I gain performance avoiding additional checks when I'm not passing an Array of disposable objects.

Comment: What happens if you have a third definition, where `T` is `IDisposable` and has a parameterless constructor (i.e. has `new`)?

Comment: Rename `InitializeAll(Of T As New)` to `CreateInitializeAll(Of T As New)`

Comment: @T.S. Changing the method name is not a valid or real solution, they have the same name to apply the method overload. thankyou anyways.

Comment: @Wai Ha Lee For "Constructor" you will mean the method signature? (a parameterless method), In that case nothing will happen, because extension methods should have declared at least 1 parameter... the source object. thanks anyways too!.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Method overloads which differ only by generic constraint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097529/method-overloads-which-differ-only-by-generic-constraint)

Comment: I've flagged your question as a duplicate of another (C#) question. [The accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1097537/1364007) by [Marc Gravell ♦](http://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell), sorry to say, basically says there's no way around this.

Comment: You are trying to do something that explicitly prohibited. Since you're trying to perform essentially 2 different actions, overload is not an appropriate approach; you have two choices - either identify them differently, or - add a parameter that will differentiate them. Your program doesn't make any sense. How will runtime identify, when you need to do `new T` and when you need do `Dospose....Activator`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real question here is **What happens when an object has a Constructor and is also IDisposable ?** Which method to call ? This is why it results in a problem.

Generic types cannot be used for overloading because the compiler has no way to diferenciate two different types at compile-time and therefore considers them the same...

So either you create a real Overload, like :

```
'Would mean you can Dispose them, but you have to load the method with Reflection
Public Overload Sub InitializeAll(of T As New)(ByVal Sender As T(), ByVal CollectionIsDisposable As Boolean)

'So here they are not disposable...
Public Overloads Sub InitializeAll(of T As New(ByVal Sender As T())
```

And there you get a real Overload, but as you said maybe it ruins your logic, then just go with one method, and check if the objects implement `IDisposable`.